How to derive the relation about Jordan decomposition of a matrix?
Assume that $v$ is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue of $0$ in matrix $H$, and its Jordan decomposition $H^J=SHS^{-1}$ satisfies
$$
H^J=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1&  \cdots&  0\\
 0&  0&  \cdots&  0\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  \ddots&  1\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) , \left( H^J \right) _{ij}=\mathrm{\delta}_{j-i,1}
$$
(from the form of $H^J$ one can find that $v$ is unique) Now prove
$$
v^J:= Sv=\left( \begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 0\\
 \vdots\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) , \left( v^J \right) _i=\mathrm{\delta}_{1i}\tag{1}
$$
When the unique eigenvalue of $H$ is not $0$, the equation $(1)$ still holds. (The diagonal elements of $H^J$ are the eigenvalue itself)
I cannot derive the relation $(1)$. Can anyone help me?

I have verified it with Mathematica, the code is as follows:
Clear["`*"];
H[n_] := 
  Table[(-2 I  i  KroneckerDelta[i, j] + 
      Sqrt[(l - j) (l + j + 1)] KroneckerDelta[i, j + 1] + 
      Sqrt[(l + j) (l - j + 1)] KroneckerDelta[i, j - 1]) /. 
    l -> n/2, {i, n/2, -n/2, -1}, {j, n/2, -n/2, -1}];

H[7] - k  IdentityMatrix[7 + 1]
{s, j} = JordanDecomposition[%];
v = Eigenvectors[%%, 1] // Transpose;
Inverse[s] . v

The $H$ in the code has a unique eigenvalue $0$ and a unique eigenvector.

Your eigenvector is the first vector of your basis used for the Jordan basis, therefore when you change basis you get $e_1$ the canonical vector... Also there is a small error you know that $v$ is unique up to multiplication by a non-zero scalar! (Here the basis is of the form $(H^{n-1}u,H^{n-2} u ,\dots ,u)$ with $H^{n-1}u \neq 0$ in the kernel of $H$

Here I try to provide a(n incomplete) method based on calculation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
H^J & =S H S^{-1} \\
H^J S \boldsymbol{v} & =S H \boldsymbol{v} \\
H^J \boldsymbol{v}^J & =S(H \boldsymbol{v}) \\
H^J \boldsymbol{v}^J & =0 \\
\left(\begin{array}{llll}
0 & 1 & & \\
& 0 & 1 & \\
& & \ddots & 1 \\
& & & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\left(\boldsymbol{v}^J\right)_1 \\
\left(\boldsymbol{v}^J\right)_2 \\
\vdots \\
\left(\boldsymbol{v}^J\right)_N
\end{array}\right) & =0 \\
\left(\boldsymbol{v}^J\right)_n & =0, n=2,3, \cdots, N \\
\boldsymbol{v}^J & =\left(\begin{array}{c}
\left(\boldsymbol{v}^J\right)_1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{array}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
But I cannot get that $(v^J)_1=1$.
We note that the transformation matrix $S$ can differ by a constant multiple, and the same can be said for the eigenvector $v$. So the conclusion of the question may be wrong and may not be $1$, but an any variable.
